# Web application with model results for use in healthcare?

Tags: r, regression, stata, marginal-distribution, application

Often in medicine we use scores, so the patient gets 1 point for this symptom, another for this etc. and a final a score determines their risk/treatment strategy.

If we have reliable data and build a multiple regression model of a large register of patients, wouldn't it be more accurate to use margins to calculate an exact percentage?

In this case you could input age, gender, symptom1, symptom2, radiologic finding1, radiologic finding2 etc. and the model (which we are assuming is very reliable) can calculate that patient's risk in percentages.

Is it possible to use either R or Stata code in a web application to build such a model and then have a margin analysis where you simply input the patient's parameter to get exact probabilities? Where would I go to get started with writing such an application?

I believe this is the most appropriate platform to ask this question as the userbase is heavily involved in these softwares and also because I would like input on the idea of developing such an application instead of a scoring system.

Comment: For a concrete application, see [predict](https://breast.predict.nhs.uk/tool) by the NHS for breast cancer. For a start, you could build a [shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) app to deploy your model.

Comment: Thanks, Shiny looks interesting. You could consider adding this as an answer.

Comment: I have experience with exposing statistical web applications to the wider internet - see my zunzun.com web site - and if possible I recommend restricting access.

Comment: James I have taken a tour of your website and I may be interested in using it for some of my research in the near future, would this platform be the best way to contact you?